# Localhost configuration problem- loading extensions "There was an error uploading this file to the server."

Tags: joomla-2.5, extensions, localhost, file-upload

Running ubuntu 14.04 Joomla 2.5.27 locally (2.5.28 remotely - not relevant to my question as far as I'm aware.)

I am having trouble configuring my site to run locally. I have the site installed on my localhost server and can browse it fine.

When I try to update to version 2.5.28 from 2.5.27 before finally looking to update to 3.5 I receive the following error message:-

"There was an error uploading this file to the server."

I have checked out question people have asked before here on stackexchange and other sites and tried various things.

1)Like changing folder permission. Currently set to 755 I believe.
2)Changing the path of the logs and tmp files to :

public $log_path = '/var/www/log';
public $tmp_path = '/var/www/tmp';

3)setting the password for my local msql database - of course,else the site wouldn't work. Root password.

4)Changed the size of the file allow in ini.php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411896/error-uploading-big-extensions-to-joomla-on-a-localhost

I'm a bit at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your $tmp_path is incorrect. It needs to be something like `C:/wamp/www/tmp` or something similar starting with your local drive path

Comment: @Lodder ... not if it is run on ubuntu I guess...

Comment: BUT did you install Joomla directly in www or is it a subdirectory? Then the subdirectory folder might be missing in your paths. Also, did you try using 775 for permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BE, navigate to

System Information > Directory Permissions

The status should be green for all folders / files, especially the `tmp` directory.

[image]

If you see this as "unwritable" you need to change this.

There is some good documentation about this in [Installing Joomla on Debian Linux](https://docs.joomla.org/Installing_Joomla_on_Debian_Linux). See the section with **Set ownerships and permissions**.

Comment: thanks - that has brilliantly sorted out my file permissions and made everything writable as I've chosen to do. If I make all folders in /var/www/html writable does that make my site less secure when I upload remotely? I can now upload files, or at least smaller ones. A 2.8MB one that was a patch won't upload. I guess this may be related to a setting on ini.php? I will research further.

Comment: It is hard to answer in a sentence. You will find some similar questions here as well as documentation on docs.joomla.org on how to set the correct file permissions.